# Why there is a type mismatch between my static method's return value and the defined constructor (in c++)?

Tags: c++, constructor, static-methods

I have a Matrix class and i want to define a static method in it to multiply two matrixes.

When i try to compile this C++ code I get an error which say "No matching constructor for initialization of 'Matrix' " !

here is my constructor signature :

```
Matrix(Matrix& A);
```

here is my multiply method :

```
static Matrix mult(Matrix &A,Matrix &B){
    if (A.n != B.m)
        throw 2;

    Matrix C(A.m,B.n);
    for (int i=0;i<A.m;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<B.n;j++){
            for (int k=0;k<A.n;k++)
                C.matrix[i][j] += A.matrix[i][k] * B.matrix[k][j];
        }
    }

    return C;
}
```

and here is the code to trigger the mult function and fill the z variable :

```
Matrix z = Matrix::mult(x,y);
```

What is the problem ?! why my constructor doesn't match with the return value ?!

This is my whole Matrix class :

```
class Matrix{
public:
    int m,n;
    bool** matrix;

    Matrix(int m,int n);
    Matrix(Matrix& A);

    int get_m();
    int get_n();
    void set(int,int,bool);
    bool get(int,int);


    Matrix& add(Matrix&);
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ,Matrix&);
    string toString();

    ~Matrix();

    static Matrix mult(Matrix &A, Matrix &B);
```

};

Comment: Have you defined an overloaded constructor to take 2 values? Also, show us your matrix class.

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your Matrix class that takes two integers?

Comment: Your copy constructor should take `const Matrix &`.

Comment: yes, `Matrix(Matrix &A)` is my copy constructor which i overload the default one. as of my knowledge, this copy constructor should match with `Matrix::mult(x,y)` return value !

Comment: sry for the last reply !

Comment: Your copy constructor is OK (save for the `const` in the signature, which is optional). However, this line `Matrix C(A.m,B.n)` needs a different constructor - one that takes two integers.

Answer (score 2):

> why my constructor doesn't match with the return value ?!

Because you are returning a local object by-value, and the only copy constructor you have provided for `Matrix` takes a non-`const` reference.  This doesn't work.

You can fix this by providing a copy constructor that takes a `const` reference:

```
Matrix(const Matrix& A);
```

Consider the following illustration of this same situation:

```
#include "main.h"

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo (int n) : mN (n) {}
    Foo (Foo& rhs) : mN (rhs.mN) {}
    int DaNum() const { return mN * 2; }
private:
    int mN;
};

Foo Gimme(int n)
{
    Foo ret(n);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
  Foo foo = Gimme (42);
  cout << foo.DaNum();
}
```

As is this fails to compile with:

```
main.cpp:21:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(Foo)’
```

...but reading further we see that the compiler continues to elaborate:

```
main.cpp:21:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(Foo)’
main.cpp:21:22: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:7:5: note: Foo::Foo(Foo&)
main.cpp:7:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo’ to ‘Foo&’
main.cpp:6:5: note: Foo::Foo(int)
main.cpp:6:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo’ to ‘int’
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Changing:

```
Foo (Foo& rhs) : mN (rhs.mN) {}
```

...to:

```
Foo (const Foo& rhs) : mN (rhs.mN) {}
```

Resolves the issue.

Comment: I didn't get the syntax `function_name(params):x(){}` but
why does my static method returns a constant object ?!

Comment: @Shnd: One of the great things about StackOverflow is you often learn about things even when you didn't ask.  Look up "initialization lists".

Comment: @Shnd:  Your static method does not return a constant object.  It returns an object by value.  What I'm suggesting is that your copy constructor take a constant refernce to the object.  Note what is constant here -- the *reference*, not the *object*.